# How can I optimize/vectorize this looped assignment on a DataFrame?

Tags: python, optimization, pandas, vectorization

Below is a function I wrote to label certain rows based on ranges of indexes.  For convenience, I'm making the two function arguments, [samples](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhs88zcnpivwrnd/samples.pickle) and [matdat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hwej6qrnepnp9l/matdat.pickle) available for download in pickle format.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import izip, imap

import pandas as pd


def _insert_design_columns(samples, matdat):
    """Add columns for design-factors, label lines that correspond to a given trials and
    then fill in said columns with the appropriate value on lines that belong to a
    trial.

    samples : DataFrame
         DataFrame of eyetracker samples.
         column `t`: time sample, in ms
         column `event`: TTL event
         columns x, y: x and y coordinates of gaze
         column cr:  corneal reflection area

    matdat : dict of numpy arrays
         dict mapping matlab variable name to numpy array

    returns : modified `samples` dataframe
    """
    ## This is fairly trivial preperation and data formatting for the nested
    #    for-loop below.  We're just fixing types, adding empty columns, and
    #    ensuring that our numpy arrays have the right shape.

    # Grab variables from the dict & squeeze the numpy arrays
    key = ('cuepos', 'targetpos', 'targetorientation', 'soa', 'normalizedResp')
    cpos, tpos, torient, soa, resp = map(pd.np.squeeze, imap(matdat.get, key))
    cpos = cpos.astype(float)
    cpos[cpos < 0] = pd.np.nan
    cong = tpos == cpos
    cong[pd.isnull(cpos)] = pd.np.nan

    # Add empty columns for each factor.  These will contain the factor level on
    # that correspond to a trial (i.e. between a `TrialStart` and `ReportCueOnset` in
    # `samples.event`
    samples['soa'] = pd.np.nan
    samples['cpos'] = pd.np.nan
    samples['tpos'] = pd.np.nan
    samples['cong'] = pd.np.nan
    samples['torient'] = pd.np.nan
    samples['normalizedResp'] = pd.np.nan

    ## This is important, but not the part we need to optimize.
    #     Here, we're finding the start and end indexes for every trial.  Trials
    #     are composed of continuous slices of rows.

    # Assign trial numbers
    tstart = samples[samples.event == 'TrialStart'].t  # each trial starts on a `TrialStart`
    tstop = samples[samples.event == 'ReportCueOnset'].t  # ... and ends on a `ReportCueOnset`
    samples['trial'] = pd.np.nan  # make an empty column which will contain trial num

    ## This is the sub-optimal part.  Here, we're iterating through our start/end index
    #    pairs, slicing the dataframe to get the rows we need, and then:
    #       1.  Assigning a trial number to that slice of rows
    #       2.  Assigning the correct value to corresponding columns (see `factor_names`)

    samples.set_index(['t'], inplace=True)
    for i, (start, stop) in enumerate(izip(tstart, tstop)):
        samples.loc[start:stop, 'trial'] = i + 1  # label the interval's trial number

        # Now that we've labeled a range of rows as a trial, we can add factor levels
        # to the corresponding columns
        idx = itemgetter(i - 1)
        # factor_values/names has the same length as the number of trials we're going to
        # find.  Get the corresponding value for the current trial so that we can
        # assign it.
        factor_values = imap(idx, (cpos, tpos, torient, soa, resp, cong))
        factor_names = ('cpos', 'tpos', 'torient', 'soa', 'resp', 'cong')
        for c, v in izip(factor_names, factor_values):  # loop through columns and assign
            samples.loc[start:stop, c] = v
    samples.reset_index(inplace=True)

    return samples
```

I've performed a `%prun`, the first few lines of which read:

```
         548568 function calls (547462 primitive calls) in 9.380 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    11360    6.074    0.001    6.084    0.001 index.py:604(__contains__)
     2194    0.949    0.000    0.949    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
     1430    0.730    0.001    0.730    0.001 {pandas.lib.infer_dtype}
     1098    0.464    0.000    0.467    0.000 internals.py:277(set)
1093/1092    0.142    0.000    9.162    0.008 indexing.py:157(_setitem_with_indexer)
     1100    0.106    0.000    1.266    0.001 frame.py:1851(__setitem__)
      166    0.047    0.000    0.047    0.000 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
   107209    0.037    0.000    0.066    0.000 {isinstance}
       14    0.029    0.002    0.029    0.002 {numpy.core.multiarray.concatenate}
39362/38266    0.026    0.000    6.101    0.000 {getattr}
7829/7828    0.024    0.000    0.030    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
     1092    0.023    0.000    0.457    0.000 internals.py:564(setitem)
        5    0.023    0.005    0.023    0.005 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis0_float64_float64}
     4379    0.021    0.000    0.108    0.000 index.py:615(__getitem__)
     1101    0.020    0.000    0.582    0.001 frame.py:1967(_sanitize_column)
     2192    0.017    0.000    0.946    0.000 internals.py:2236(apply)
        8    0.017    0.002    0.017    0.002 {method 'repeat' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

Judging by the line that reads `1093/1092    0.142    0.000    9.162    0.008 indexing.py:157(_setitem_with_indexer)`, I strongly suspect my nested loop assignment with `loc` to be the culprit.  The whole function takes about 9.3 seconds to execute and has to be performed 144 times in total (i.e. ~22 minutes).

**Is there a way to vectorize or otherwise optimize the assignment I'm trying to do?**

Comment: It'd help if your function had better [comments](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments).

Comment: @SteveS, I'm not quite sure what comments I can provide that would be meaningful.  The code is fairly self-documenting insofar as what it *does*.  *Why* this is being done requires knowledge of the experiment that gave rise to the data.  Is there any part in particular that's unclear?

Comment: @SteveS, I added a few comments in the hopes that it makes things clearer.  In short, for each iteration of the outer loop, I want to select a range of rows and label corresponding columns (see `factor_names`).  Everything before the first for-loop is preparation (creating empty columns, fixing data types, finding start and end indexes for the intervals of rows we want.  Again, I'd be happy to provide additional details if this is still too confusing. =)

Comment: Google's approach to Docstrings is really effective: descibe args, describe output, and describe a little about what function does (but not implementation). It sort of primes the reader of the code (so then you (the reader) know what to look for, etc. as you dive in to the code.

Comment: @SteveS, docstring added

Comment: It's looking *better*. But why is all this crap in only a *single* function in the first place??

Comment: As an aside, if you're going to post your data, it helps if you include in your script a couple lines to actually load in the data so someone reading your question can just copy and paste it all and not have to write those extra lines themselves. And post it in some boring filetype like **csv**.

Comment: @SteveS, I mean absolutely no disrespect, but I'd appreciate it if we could tackle the meat of the question.  I've put in a fair effort in clarifying and formatting this question.  The code is readable and I does a good job of illustrating what data we're working with and what I'm attempting to do.  It's becoming hard not to take your comments as nitpicking, and your tone in your second-to-last comment borders on insulting.  Again, I mean *absolutely* no disrespect, and if you have a *specific* question about something (or if something *specific* is unclear), I'd of course be happy to clarify.

Comment: No problem. As a general rule of thumb, you should never download **pickles** from the Internet (think: "Stranger Danger!")--that's why I mentioned the **csv** filetype. Also, since I haven't downloaded your actual data, I have a pretty poor idea of what it actually looks like as well as the structure of most of the variables in your code or even why you'd have to run it 144 times anyway. Then there are other things I'm not getting such as why you're using "i-1" as an argument.

Comment: Why not--after labeling the interval's trial number (and instead of creating all new column's with NaNs)--you assign the appropriate values via some sort of left join instead? (i.e. using pandas **merge** function--is there some reason why that's not possible?)